# Theming Material Light

Tags: html, web, material-design-lite

I've been trying to port my website https://lavanoid.github.io to a more "Google Standard" but it's been really frustrating (thanks to Google, not well documenting stuff, as far as I can see :/).

I've been trying to theme this template: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/templates/text-only  but it isn't going so well. I can't even find how to change the color, which is the most important part.

So, how do I change the purple color to the hex value of #2196f3 ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would need to change:

```
.mdl-color--primary {
    background-color: #5e35b1 !important;
}
```

To this:

```
.mdl-color--primary {
    background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you :D May I ask where this goes? I scanned the styles.css and index.html but can't find '.mdl-color--primary' :/

Comment: OOps. It's in the material CS. Thanks!